How does it work to ignore the redirects of stdout and stderr and write directly to console?
How does ssh ignore the redirect and write anyways to the console?
.\ssh.exe user@127.0.0.1 -p 1022 -v > test.log 2>&1

Output shown on windows console (perhaps the same under linux?):
The authenticity of host '[127.0.0.1]:1022 ([127.0.0.1]:1022)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:xeS1I/8fteLkGqn43X0VkBpBgY7IIAo9Ysy69r/8iHQ.
This key is not known by any other names.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?

I know, the message is for interactive interaction and thus does not makes sense to be redirected, but how does that work?
The code in charge for ssh should be this function:
static int
confirm(const char *prompt, const char *fingerprint)
{
    const char *msg, *again = "Please type 'yes' or 'no': ";
    const char *again_fp = "Please type 'yes', 'no' or the fingerprint: ";
    char *p, *cp;
    int ret = -1;

    if (options.batch_mode)
        return 0;
    for (msg = prompt;;msg = fingerprint ? again_fp : again) {
        cp = p = read_passphrase(msg, RP_ECHO);
        if (p == NULL)
            return 0;
        p += strspn(p, " \t"); /* skip leading whitespace */
        p[strcspn(p, " \t\n")] = '\0'; /* remove trailing whitespace */
        if (p[0] == '\0' || strcasecmp(p, "no") == 0)
            ret = 0;
        else if (strcasecmp(p, "yes") == 0 || (fingerprint != NULL &&
            strcmp(p, fingerprint) == 0))
            ret = 1;
        free(cp);
        if (ret != -1)
            return ret;
    }
}

Where prompt contains the string shown on the console. Going deeper, the magic should happen in read_passphrase(msg, RP_ECHO)... where my C knowledge ends.

What did you search for, and what did you find? What did you try, and how did it fail? The code is at https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/cc80d51d034bcb24fd0f2564a4bdf1612000a2a2/sshconnect.c#L850

read_passphrase is the function that's actually doing the writing. Spoiler alert: it simply doesn't write to standard output, but to the controlling terminal directly.

@chepner I also found that function and think it writes to _PATH_TTY "/dev/tty". Am I correct that the message is most likely written to the terminal, because they read user input later and that is only possible via a TTY? That's my assumption. In C# (my background) there is no way that i know of, to write directly to a terminal, thus i was so surprised.

/dev/tty is the file representing the process's controlling terminal. ssh could read this information from standard input, but it's considered a security feature to read from the terminal directly (not so much because it's inherently more secure, I think, but because it eliminates a reason to store passwords in an insecure on-disk file or hard-coded in a script).
